# Send Confidential email through gmail api

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to send Confidential emails via gmail, although I am not sure it is supported. Via the gmail API, the User.messages fields do not seem to indicate whether an email is confidential or not. I retrieved a confidential and regular email via the v1 gmail api get method and the messages are identical. Is there a way send a confidential gmail email, either with the official api or other service?

Comment: As DalmTo said, it is currently not supported through the API. However, you can [post a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) for it to be added to the API.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the google issue tracker. I see there are already a couple feature requests for this. [original issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134368396) and [duplicate issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140388008)

Comment: You can use the +1 button to show you're also having the same request and increase its priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowlage you can't send messages with "Confidential mode" through the Gmail API.   This is not currently supported.

Comment: Okay, I thought so but thought I'd ask since no where explicitly stated it wasn't supported. Thank you for the answer, I'll update this when / if the feature is added.

Comment: As developers we document what is possible because if we also documented what wasn't possible we wouldn't have time to code anything

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo : Is there anyway to identify confidential email using Gmail API ? i.e. any meta data which can be used to differentiate between normal emails and confidential emails ?

Comment: Awesome question I have no idea.   I would try and grab an email via the api and check all the headers i wouldn't be surprised if there isnt something hiding in there.